# Alternatives to Poisson Distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, modeling, poisson-process

Imagine a data set that has information about how frequently various people visit a location $l$ over a year ($l$ could be a restaurant or a public park). What would be a good way to analyze this data?

I have thought of the following: Consider a person $p$ that has visited $l$ at least once. Suppose that $p$'s visits to $l$ are independent of each other. In this case, $p$'s visits can be modeled as a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda$. Using our data set, we could determine the expected value, variance, etc of $\lambda$ over all people $p$.

However, this reasoning could possibly be invalid since people might be more likely to visit $l$ during certain days, for example, Saturdays.

Are there any other ways to analyze this data set that takes into account the fact that people are more likely to visit $l$ during certain times?

Answer (score 1):

There are several generalizations of the Poisson process.  The one that should interest you is the inhomogeneous Poisson process. It simply assumes that the rate parameter varies with time.  In your case, you could assume that the rate parameter differs by day of the week. This would give you seven rate parameters to estimate from your data.